# What does "skim away" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw this in a book called *The Garden Party*:

> Away she skimmed, over the lawn, up the path, up the steps, across the veranda, and into the porch.

Can someone explain this phrase in simple English?

Comment: It's a ***metaphoric*** reference. Effectively, the way she moved away gave the appearance of her "floating" across the grass and up the path (only gently / briefly touching the ground the way a skimmed stone briefly touches the water surface).

Answer (score 1):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of the verb [**skim**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skim):

> 5 : to pass swiftly or lightly over

And from its definition of the adverb [**along**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/away):

> 1 : on the way : ALONG

---

In short:

> *[Along the way (to the house)],* she *[passed swiftly and lightly]* over the lawn, up the path, up the steps, across the veranda, and into the porch.

Or, to phrase it more naturally:

> Away she went, without disturbance, swiftly over the lawn, up the path, up the steps, across the veranda, and into the porch.